# My BiBtex isn't compiling properly for articles

Tags: bibtex

One of my references

```
@Article{Normark00c,
author =     {Kurt Nørmark},
title =      {Elucidative Programming},
journal =    {Nordic Journal of Computing},
year =   {2000},
volume =     {7},
number =     {2},
pages =        {87--105}
}
```

The output should look like

> [2000, article]
>       K. Nørmark, "Elucidative Programming," *Nordic Journal of Computing*, vol. 7, iss. 2, pp. 87-105, 2000.

But in my LaTeX, I got

> K. Nrmark, Nordic Journal of Computing 7, 87 (2000).

Instead. My output completely skips the title of the article…

My LaTeX Code is something like this

```
 \documentclass[15pt]{article} 

 \usepackage{parskip}
 \usepackage{mathtools}
 \usepackage{graphicx}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{amssymb}
 \usepackage{mdframed}
 \usepackage{dsfont}
 \usepackage{hyperref}

 \begin{document}

 \cite{Normark00c}

 \bibliographystyle{phaip} 
 \bibliography{science}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: Can you add the LaTeX code that you're using? A complete, minimal example of a document that reproduces the problem will help us spot the problem.

Comment: And welcome to TeX.SX! If I had to guess, you need to specify a different citation style in your LaTeX. Of course, it's impossible to tell without an example.

Comment: @SeanAllred, right on the jackpot! I just tried plain and it worked. Very weird.

Comment: What other style do you suggest?

Comment: Honestly, `plain` is fine for my purposes. It is my understanding that most journals have particular styles that they adhere to; if you plan to publish, you might as well use their style.

Comment: Would you consider accepting my answer below so this question may be marked as resolved?  To do so, just hit the tick/checkmark and it will turn green.

Answer (score 2):

Just change the style of your bibliography to `plain` (or [another style](http://www.cs.stir.ac.uk/~kjt/software/latex/showbst.html) that suits you):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} % note 15pt option does not exist
...
\cite{Normark00c}
...
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{science}
...
\end{document}
```